# What's the deal with this Exception error that pops up in my Rock Paper Scissors game?

Tags: java, exception, error-handling, compiler-errors, nullpointerexception

Exception in thread"main"
java.lang.NullPointerException (at line 49 and 14)

```
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {
    static String pInp;
    static int cpuInp;
    static Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    public static void main(String args[]) {
System.out.print("Rock, Paper, or Scissors");
playerGo(pInp);
compGo(cpuInp);
checkWin(cpuInp, pInp);  **LINE 14**
            }
public static void playerGo(String pInp) {
    
     pInp = scan.nextLine();
    switch (pInp) {
    case "Rock" :
        System.out.println("Player chose Rock");
        break;
    case "Paper" :
        System.out.println("Player chose Paper");
        break;
    case "Scissors" :
        System.out.println("Player chose Scissors");
        break;
    }   
}
public static void compGo(int cpuInp) {
    Random rand = new Random();
     cpuInp = rand.nextInt(3);
    
    switch (cpuInp) {
    case 0 :
        System.out.println("Computer chose Rock");
        break;
    case 1 :
        System.out.println("Computer chose Paper");
        break;
    case 2 :
        System.out.println("Computer chose Scissors");
        break;
    }   
    
}
public static void checkWin(int cpuInp, String pInp) {
**LINE 49** if (cpuInp==0 && pInp.equals("Rock") || cpuInp==1 && pInp.equals("Paper") || cpuInp==2 && pInp.equals("Scissors")) {
        System.out.println("Tie");
    
} else if (cpuInp==0 && pInp.equals("Paper") || cpuInp==1 && pInp.equals("Scissors") || cpuInp==2 && pInp.equals("Rock")) {
    System.out.print("Player Win");
} else if (pInp.equals("Rock") && cpuInp==1 || pInp.equals("Paper") && cpuInp==2 || pInp.equals("Scissors") && cpuInp==0) {
    System.out.print("Computer Win");
}


}
}
```

I tried to make a rock paper scissors game. The first two methods for player and computer inputs work but the method to check who wins comes up with an exception error.

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
> at (Line 49)
> at (Line 14)

(Lines that made error are pointed out in code)

Comment: When you assign a value to `pInp` in `playerGo` you are not changing the value of `static String pInp;` so it will remain `null`.  The "short" answer would be to remove the parameter requirements for both `playerGo` and `compGo`.  I would the go the extra step of having those methods return their results, so you can then assign the results back to your variables.